# How can I edit macOS system localization files?

Tags: macos, internationalization

Recently, Apple has decided to force gendered expressions in the German locale. They say there is no way to undo this, so I've been trying to sniff out a way to change the affected strings on my own.

I've found some translation files inside `/usr/share/locale` and `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations`, but they do not contain what I am looking for.

One exact thing I am looking for is the label for "Users & Groups" in the system settings menu. Anybody have an idea where these strings are stored and if and how they're editable?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

They're located in /System/Library/PreferencePanes, within whatever the Users & Groups prefpane is called. If you're on 10.15 or later, you won't be able to edit them without significant effort. This is due to macOS now using a "signed system volume" which, by default, mounts the system partition as read-only. If you do manage to mount it as read/write, you'll have to go to additional steps to prevent macOS from checking for modifications.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the directory **Benutzer:innen**, which is technically a grammar mistake since that word is not legal in Austria's official language guideline „Österreichisches Wörterbuch“ for example.

See [Kleine Zeitung](https://www.kleinezeitung.at/kultur/5940380/12000-Kunstbegriffe_Gendern-laut-Duden_Von-der-Gaestin-bis-zur) and [Der Standard](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000124706827/woerterbuch-herausgeberin-eine-feigenblattdiskussion).

A quick workaround would be deleting the file **/Users/.localized**, which would leave the directory name unlocalized.

Answer (score 0):

The strings you are looking for are in `System/Library/Core Services/SystemFolderLocalzations/de.lprojSystemFolderLocalizations.strings`.
This is a simple XML file with a dictionary of key-string pairs, like that:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
> "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
> <plist version="1.0">
> <dict>
> <key>Applications
> <string>Programme
> <key>Compositins
> <string>Kompositionen
> <key>Configuration
> <string>Konfiguration
> <key>Deleted Users
> <string>Gelöschte Benutzer:innen
> [snip]

The offending string is in the last line.

However, this is on a read-only volume, even when you mount it from a different OS instance and have to navigate to it through /Volumes. `csrutil disable` won't change this, either.

Orwellian Newspeak is real and forced upon us without having a choice.